# NUnit Integration with teamcity

Tags: nunit, teamcity

I tried a lot,but still not getting proper link and articles which can sort out my problem.

I have some NUnit test(s),which I want to integrate with team city server,for this I am using NUnit runner type in Teamcity,i gave my dll file path from which test has to execute,but after a while its giving "This build is probably hanging".

Do i need to do any additional configurations for this?
Can anyone help me out in this.

Here i am attaching my NUnit build runner configuration also.

[image][image]

Comment: what is TeamCity write to build log? May be problem in your tests?

Comment: Where can i check build logs?,for your reference i am sending you the test which i am using for this.

Comment: Click on build result and there will be 'Build Log' tab.

Comment: Hey Pavel,I changed my Run Test on : value from foldername/bin/debug/testing.dll to **\testing.dll. After this i am getting error like  No assemblies were found.
[03:52:02][Step 2/3] No assemblies were found.
[03:52:02][Step 2/3] Process exited with code -1.In the above test i am trying to check if particular page exists or not(404 error)

Comment: I check my build log based on my previous configurations, and its showing:Start TeamCity NUnit Test Runner
[04:44:20][Step 2/3] Running NUnit-2.6.0 tests under .NET Framework v4.0 x64
[04:44:22][Step 2/3]Mydll.dll (running for 17m:53s) and gave build is probably hanging message. any hopes?????

Comment: Try change test for something simpler without WebRequest to localize problem.

Comment: can u please send me a simple test for checking 404 aor any other simple test case,so that i can get an idea of how to write these cases.Thing is i have written some 5 test cases and all 5 are working fine if i am testing in my local system.

Comment: Just try test like public void Test() { Assert.IsTrue(true); } If it works fine then problem in some user rights and TeamCity build agent can't perform WebRequest. In this case check firewall and user rights under whom TeamCity build agent starts.

Comment: what are the prerequisites of getting this done? (1) Is selenium server should be there in the server where team city resides?,(2) is Nunit should be there in that machine with the same version which we used for creating test?..please reply its very urget....

Comment: I'm no sure about selenium, nunit boxed with TeamCity so you should only select right version in select box.

Comment: First of all check are you able to access urls which you are testing from TeamCity machine and user.

Comment: yes,i am able to access url from team city machine.

Comment: Maybe you build your project in Release configuration, but trying to find the testing.dll in debug folder (Folder_Name/bin/Debug/testing.dll). In any case hardcode configuration name in strings is a bad idea. Better approaches are using wildcards in file paths (like '**\bin\**\*.Tests.dll') or using TeamCity build parameters.

Answer (score 2):

I can say a couple of things that perhaps can be useful in your case.

1. Make sure the you have correct name for your Test project.

So it should be like MyProject001.Tests. Also namespaces should be the same and finally output DLL should look like MyProject001.Tests.dll

2. Make sure that you have MyProject001.Tests.dll in the correct folder locally and you commit it via SVN properly as well.
3. Sometimes `Auto MSIL` option is not a good decision.
4. Under NUnit settings I use path like ***/**/BuildOutput/MyProject001.Tests.dll
5. Also setup corret .NET framework version.

I hope it will help you somehow. Keep smiling, bro!

P.S.

In my C# code I have got

```
 [TestFixture]
    public class TestClass
    {

        [TestCase]
        public void Test0001()
        {
            // blah blah
            Assert.AreEqual(true, result);
        } 

    }
```